# How do I check if object fit is supported for video

Tags: html, css

I am using a video as a background and set its styling with `object-fit` property:

```
@supports(object-fit: cover) {
    .video {
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
```

Works good for all browsers that do and don't support `object-fit` cover, except Edge which *supports* `object-fit: cover;` but does not support it for videos. How do I check if it support `object-fit` for videos specifically?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  It's a real pain - I think a polyfill is probably your best bet.  On a related note you can vote for this property to be included on video elements for Microsoft Edge here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-eleme

Comment: @TheChewy, I just added another property MS Edge doesn't support to the @supports condition (e.g. `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility`). This is a really bad solution and probably will cause issues someday, but hopefully Edge will implement video support by then.

Comment: @sdvnksv and others: very clever idea, and as of today, Edge 18 *supports* optimizeLegibility  See caniuse.com: https://caniuse.com/#search=optimizeLegibility

Answer (score -4):

Using progressive enhancement, selecting first for browsers and then overwriting for browsers which can use it?

```
video {
 // css for browsers which are not supporting object-fit: cover for video tag ....
}
@supports (object-fit: cover) {
    video {
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
```

Or [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)?

Comment: Edge *does* support `object-fit: cover;`, so the `@supports` statement will work in this case. But practically, it *does not* support it for video files.

Comment: I understand that, in Edge case the first rule will be applied to video tag, the second one even if it will be applied will not work.